# Is iPhone on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, brand, specific-question

...When it looks and acts like Windows Mobile?

[image]

The theme is [OS7](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEgQtwIwBA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgvBnUNDDFM&ei=qrNOULnjDqWtygGJoIGABg&usg=AFQjCNEjbAgfa4nIG9DV4wpRqFQtnNzDqw&sig2=W5pwsQud9VRdyK6ZEv0ADA) for jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: Launcher 7 is a similar thing for Android.

Comment: This site is much like OS then appearance. If it looks like a dog, bark like a dog and smell like a dog is not the same as to be a dog. ;)

Answer (score 7):

It's unlikely to be a faithful reimplementation of the entire OS, and its features - as such answers to questions about it are not going to be helpful to those with a Windows Phone, and only people who have installed the package on their iPhone. That wouldn't make it a good fit for *this* site, in my opinion.

Comment: [Trying to get mod support to rename site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308700/rename-windowsphone-se-to-windowsmobile-se)